# Continue bittorrent downloads on a different computer?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm using Bit Lord as my Bittorrent client.  Is it possible to continue torrent downloads on other computer?

I'm at about 38% of the 8GB file that I'm downloading.  What do I need to do in order to continue this download on another computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

- The .torrent file
- The data downloaded so far

Move the data to the download folder on the new computer and add the torrent file. It should check the directory and notice that data is there. It should hash verify that data and continue downloading where you left off.

Comment: so I will just have to open up the .torrent file again on the other computer and save the downloaded data in the directory that I will choose in the download location of that torrent file?

Comment: same technique works for continuing a torrent download in other situations (in a VM, under the secondary OS in a dual-boot system, in a new file location on the original computer, etc).

Comment: @user, @quack is correct. This will work wherever you are moving the torrent.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the data already fetched and .torrent file, yes, you can continue, why not?

Otherwise, how the client should establish what to download and what not? Bittorrent is a piece-by-piece system, I can't really remember some client goes with direct download from first piece to last piece, it fetches pieces when they are available. Maybe it is possible with some hack or customization but I never seen that before... but if that's possible with some existing torrent client, please drop me a prooflink on that.

Comment: Is it possible if the torrent client(bitlord) is just installed. Because I'm going to install it on the internet cafe which has fast internet. But the problem is they have deep freeze installed, and if the computer restarts my download will be over

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question beyond "yes it's possible"...