# transfer bittorrent download to new computer

Tags: file-transfer, bittorrent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continue bittorrent downloads on a different computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/132154/continue-bittorrent-downloads-on-a-different-computer)

Hi

I'm not very good at this torrent business! ive downloaded 20gb of a 100gb torrent, wiped hdd and reinstalled windows (i downloaded it to my external hdd). I have the downloaded folder and have got the actual torrent file back off the website. I'm using bittorent. I know it should be possible somehow! What do i do now? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Place the content in the same location as it was on the previous computer and open the torrent file with your torrent client. Ensure the download location is pointed to the old content. After an integrity check it should continue downloading again.

**Note**: I would make a copy of the content just in case anything is overwritten.